# Increasing the input impedance of analog input using an op-amp buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc

I'm trying to sample a 0-10V DC voltage as an input to my circuit. I use the following circuit to achieve this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNsgwP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem I have is that the op-amp consumes about 500uA from the input signal (in 1.7V signal) which is not good for my application. I want to decrease this current as much as possible. I'm using the general-purpose LM358 op-amp for this circuit.

Could replacing this op-amp solve the problem, or should I make changes to the circuit?

Comment: Why are you saying "consumes about 500uA **from** the input signal"? Do you mean the input bias current (which should be much smaller), or the supply current? And what are you using as the op-amp supply?

Comment: Sorry! My bad English. Yes I mean the input bias current from my analog input source.

Comment: The first page it LM358 datasheet tells me 500 uA is the supply current. Are you sure 500 uA is the bias current? According to the datasheet, maximum bias current at room temperature is 100 nA.

Comment: Your opamp is not powered. Probably you want to use a single positive supply, not a positive and negative supply needed by most FET-input opamps since their inputs do not work within a few volts near the negative supply voltage.

Comment: How is the op-amp connected to its power rails?

Comment: @LongPham I checked the circuit I had put a Schottky diode between the GND and Input pin to protect it from negative voltage. I removed it and the input current is about 100nA but the output voltage of the op-amp is not zero now. Should I put a very large pull-down res on the input pin of the op-amp?

Answer (score 1):

consider replacing the LM358 by an equivalent op-amp but with **FET** input transistors (or such that higher imput impedance is obtained).

Comment: Can you give me some part numbers?

Comment: Hi, frankly you would be best to know what is your requirement ... what power supply, single supply or double etc. But believe me if you do a search on some of the most common op-amp vendors around, or do a search with required parameters on Mouser or Digikey, you will narrow-down to just a few parts that will suit your application. Then you can also set the limit for how much you want to pay for such a part etc ... good luck